# Using EC2 instance profile with IAM authentication in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, rds

I set up IAM authentication on an RDS instance, and I'm able to use IAM to get database passwords that work for 15-minutes. This is fine to access the database for backups, but this database backs an web application so currently after 15 minutes the password used by the app to connect to the DB becomes invalid and the app crashes as it can no longer access the DB.

However, in the [RDS IAM docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html) there's this line:

> For applications running on Amazon EC2, you can use EC2 instance profile credentials to access the database, so you don't need to use database passwords on your EC2 instance.

This implies that on EC2 there's no need to use the IAM temporary DB password, which would mean that my app should be able to connect to the DB as long as it's running on EC2 and I set up the role permissions (which I think I did correctly). However, I can't get my app running on EC2 to be able to connect to the RDS DB except by using the 15-minute temporary password. If I try connecting with a normal MySQL connection with no password I get permission denied. Is there something special that needs to be done to connect to RDS using the EC2 instance profile, or is it not possible without using 15-minute temporary passwords?

Answer (score 2):

> For applications running on Amazon EC2, you can use EC2 instance profile credentials to access the database, so you don't need to use database passwords on your EC2 instance.

You're misinterpreting what this means.  It means you don't have to use *static* passwords or store them on the instance.

The idea is that you generate a new authentication token each time you establish a connection to the database.  The token is generated on your instance, using the instance role credentials.  It can only be used to authenticate for 15 minutes, but once connected, you don't lose your database connection after 15 minutes.  You remain connected.

If your application doesn't reuse database connections, then you likely have a design flaw there.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you linked (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html), you need to perform the following steps (See under "Authenticating to a DB Instance or DB Cluster Using IAM Database Authentication"):

1. Use the AWS SDK for Java or AWS CLI to get an authentication token you can use to identify the IAM user or role. To learn how to get an authentication token, see Getting an Authentication Token.
2. Connect to the database using an SSL connection, specifying the IAM user or role as the database user account and the authentication token as the password. For more information, see Connecting to a DB Instance or DB Cluster Using IAM Database Authentication.

That means for every connection you intend to open, you need to get a valid Token using the AWS SDK. This is where using the correct instance profile with the RDS permission is needed. See also the code examples further down the AWS documentation page.

I think however this requires quite a bit of effort on your side, to always get a valid token before opening a connection. It makes using an off-the-shelf connection pool difficult. Probably once open, the connection will remain open even after the token expires, but you still need to handle the case where more connections need to be opened at a later time.

I would stick with a normal user/password access for the application, using IAM for this case seems to be too much effort.

Comment: Just to confirm, connection does remain open even after 15 minutes.